# Como importar um arquivo com extensão .er1 no CA Data Modeling

Tags: modelagem, modelo-relacional, diagrama

Preciso importar um arquivo .er1 de uma versão antiga do Erwin no CA Data Modeling (Community Edition).

Isto é possível ?

Tentei abrir direto e as opções de "Import" sem sucesso.

Grato por qualquer ajuda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a pesquisa efectuada a resposta é **Não**, o *CA Data Modeling (Community Edition)*  deixou de suportar o formato `.er1`.

Fonte é esta thread:
[Link](https://communities.ca.com/thread/2276042)

mais propriamente este comentário:

> Unfortunately, CA ERwin Data Modeler Community Edition (CE) cannot
>   open ".er1" files. That is one of the limitations in this product
>   version. You'll have to convert the file to a ".erwin" file using the
>   commercial version of the product. Another approach is to FE the
>   ".er1" model using an appropriate version of CA ERwin Data Modeler and
>   then RE using CA ERwin Data Modeler CE. More information on CA ERwin
>   Data Modeler CE is located at: www.ca.com/erwin/community.

Pelo que li, deverás de arranjar algum programa que consiga abrir essa extensão, salvar como `xml` e depois sim tentar importar CA Data Modeling (Community Edition).

[Link 1](http://www.metaintegration.net/Products/MIMB/Specifications/MIRCaErwin4XmlImport.html)

[Link 2](http://sybase.public.powerdesigner.general.narkive.com/pOAHL3Ji/erwin-file-import)

Comment: Parece mesmo jsantos , terei de pensar outra alternativa , preciso recuperar a documentação de um sistema legado da empresa em que trabalho. Quando o SO liberar repasso seus pontos. []´s